# add class one by one when mouseenter event

Tags: javascript, typescript

i want add a class (.fill class )to each children of when i have mouse hover on each of them

i wrote this code in typescript and i add mouseenter event  but when i open file the .fill class is already applied to all of them why ?

```
class Rate {
    private stars : any ;

    constructor(){
        this.init()
    }

    init(){
        this.stars = document.querySelectorAll("#rating div");
        for (let i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++){
            this.stars[i].setAttribute('count', i);
            this.stars[i].addEventListener("mouseenter",this.fill(this.stars[i]))

        }
    }
    fill(elm){
        elm.classList.add("fill")
    }
}

let a   =  new Rate()
```

html

```
<div id="rating" class="rating">
<div ><i class="ion-android-star"></i></div>
<div ><i class="ion-android-star"></i></div>
<div ><i class="ion-android-star"></i></div>
<div ><i class="ion-android-star"></i></div>
<div ><i class="ion-android-star"></i></div>
</div>
```

compiled js:

```
var Rate = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Rate() {
        this.init();
    }
    Rate.prototype.init = function () {
        this.stars = document.querySelectorAll("#rating div");
        for (var i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++) {
            this.stars[i].setAttribute('count', i);
            this.stars[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", this.fill(this.stars[i]));
        }
    };
    Rate.prototype.fill = function (elm) {
        elm.classList.add("fill");
    };
    return Rate;
}());
var a = new Rate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function that performs the action, right now you execute the fill immediately in the `init` functions. The easiest way to do this is to use an arrow function.

```
init(){
    this.stars = document.querySelectorAll("#rating div");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++){
        this.stars[i].setAttribute('count', i);
        this.stars[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", () => this.fill(this.stars[i]))

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use addEventListener like that, the function will be executed..

this will work:

```
class Rate {
    private stars : any ;

    constructor(){
        this.init()
    }

    init(){
        this.stars = document.querySelectorAll("#rating div");
        for (let i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++){
            this.stars[i].setAttribute('count', i);
            this.stars[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", this.fill);

        }
    }
    fill(e){
        e.target.classList.add("fill");
    }
}

let a   =  new Rate()
```